How to change the inlay_hints position on Neovim 0.10.0?
On NVIM v0.10.0 inlay_hints are shown on inline, which changes the code visual and make lines longer.
How to change inlay_hints to show end-of-line instead in-line?
Actual:

Expected:


The positioning of extmarks depends on the arguments passed into nvim_buf_set_extmark(). Specifically, see the virt_text_pos option. It looks like your "actual" screenshot is set to "inline", but your "expected" screenshot is set to "eol" instead.
Whatever it is that's creating those extmarks needs to call the nvim extmark API with the proper argument in order to set the positioning of the extmarks the way you want.
